# Is 13 days enough processing time to get a Schengen VISA (German consulate, San Francisco)?

Tags: schengen, germany

Sorry I'm not sure if I can ask two questions one after the other (I already posted another one barely half an hour ago), so please let me know if I should take this down.

I had originally wanted to travel to Germany, and have already booked tickets to and from Frankfurt. But the appointment date I got for the German consulate is 13 days before I fly. Is this cutting it too close?

Because of this I looked for an appointment with another Schengen country's consulate, and got one for Belgium, that's about a month earlier. But with this I'd have to change my travel itinerary, and I'm not sure I would want to spend close to three weeks in Belgium.

What should I do? Am I being too paranoid about the German Schengen VISA appointment? Or should I go ahead with the Belgium one and just suck it up and make this trip all about Belgium?

Comment: Belgium has enough to keep you busy, if you are willing to spend effort in finding what you like.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [German Missions in the United States](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/03__FAQ/Visa/__FAQ__Visa.html) website:

> How long will I have to wait for my visa?
>
> **The processing time for visa applications (short stay) takes up to 15
>   days.** If long-term residence permits or visa for employment in Germany
>   are applied for, the processing time will be up to several months.

Therefore 13 days is cutting it close and I wouldn't risk it.